# scanner of Samsung SCX-4200 does not work on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, samsung, scanner

I have a Samsung SCX-4200 multifunction printer/scanner which works fine under Windows 8. The printer works fine under Ubuntu 12.10, but the scanner doesn't work.

"sudo sane-find-scanner" find nothing. While "scanimage -L" get: "device `xerox_mfp:libusb:003:016' is a SAMSUNG ORION multi-function peripheral".

When use "xsane", it says there is no scanner. How can I do?

Comment: I follow the installation guides in "README.linux". Now both "sane-find-scanner" and "scanimage -L" cannot find the scanner.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of an old question, but I had similar issues in Ubuntu 18.04.

The problem in my case was USB3. After putting the cable to an USB2 input, it worked all fine.

This has been discussed here (in french language): https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2023391